# JSON_SEARCH and Regex in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

My JSON looks like

```
user1--> 
{"feeds": [{"trait": "ms", "rating": "5", "observation": "fstress", "riskscaling": "3"}, {"trait": "es", "rating": "7", "observation": "abcde", "riskscaling": 6}], "ad_countryCode": "91"}
```

If I want to find value for a user having `fstress` then I am using query as-

```
SELECT DISTINCT globalusers.id 
FROM globalusers 
WHERE (JSON_SEARCH(dynamic_attributes->>'$.feeds[*].observation','all', 'fstress'));
```

then I am getting my user id but now I want to use regex to find user having `{fstress}`
Any one help?

Comment: care to give an example for such a user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just include the string `fstress`  ?

```
SELECT globalusers.id FROM `globalusers ` WHERE address REGEXP 'fstress';
```

Comment: This qry worked for me-->SELECT globalusers.id FROM globalusers WHERE dynamic_attributes->>'$.feeds[*].observation' REGEXP 'fstress';

Answer (score 0):

Working Qry for the same-->
SELECT globalusers.id FROM globalusers WHERE dynamic_attributes->>'$.feeds[*].observation' REGEXP 'fstress';